# Which Linux distribution and backup software should I use for Oracle backups

Tags: linux, backup, oracle

I want to install Linux with an Oracle database on it and configure Oracle to make weekly backups.

Please, advice me which distribution I should install. Also, how do I confugure my database to make weekly backups automatically?

I think Red Hat would be better and weekly backups can be configured by EM, right?

Comment: Is rad hat free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're only doing this for a test, then CentOS 5 will work just fine.
I use cron to run RMAN dumps to local disk...then I have Arkeia set to perform scheduled backups of the file system nightly.

I manage disk space by using the Arkeia "Command After Savepack" feature to delete the old Oracle images.

Comment: Thank you a lot... I will take into the consideration your advice.
I have installed CentOS 6.0, there was several choices and I choosed "Database Server".(Correct yes?)
Now I have only command line interface. 
Oracle needs /tmp to be 400M but when i run the following:
#df -h
**-----OUTPUT IS
/ - 50G
/dev/shm 1.9G
/home 174G**

The is no tmp...
I looked into fstab:

tmpfs /dev/shm   tmpfs defaults 0 0

There is such kind of enty... does it mean that /dev/shm is like /tmp directory?

How should I allocate spaces? How to mount /tmp in my case?

Comment: I did the following: in fstab I changed  
**tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0** by **tmpfs /tmp tmpfs size=400M 0 0** and rebooted the system.. 

I think I guessed correctly what to do...

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps you need to consider:

1. Choice of Linux distribution: Wich one does your company support? Perhaps you are forced to choose an enterprise edition of Red Hat or SUSE to comply to company policies?
2. Choice of backup software. Your company probably have some kind of backup software already, maybe there is an agent for Oracle?
3. Stiching all this together: Perhaps you should talk to the consultant/vendor who installed Oracle?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want to set up such system for testing purposes...
I don't have any backup yet... I need just database to make weekly backups automatically and if necessary restore&recover it

No OS and database is installed yet.. So everything should be started from zero..

I am planning to install CentOS and Oracle 10g and configure backups by Enterprise Manager... Not bad choice yes?

Answer (score 1):

Choice of backup software/strategy is likely more of an issue than Linux distribution.  Oracle has their own distribution which may be appropriate either as the base or a VM.  Your software choice may limit your options for Linux distributions.

Backing up a running Oracle database is possible, but requires co-ordination between the backup software and Oracle.  Do some research on hot backups and cold backups for Oracle.

Oracle also has its own RMan software to backup the database to tape or disk.  This makes it easier to schedule hop backups.